# PHP/Mysql "check the manual ... for the right syntax to use near '@yahoo.com'"

Tags: php, sql

I'm a new grue with php, When I write this code:

```
$query2="SELECT `User_id` FROM `users` WHERE `E-mail`=$email";
$sql2= mysql_query($query2);
if(mysql_num_rows( $sql2)>0){
   $Name2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2); 
   $customer_id=$Name2[0];
   echo $customer_id."ccccccccccc";
}
else{
     $errormessage2="<font color='red'>Invalid Email,Try 
     again</font>"."Error description: ";
}
if($sql2 === FALSE) { 
   cho "erro";
   echo mysql_error();
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

I'm getting this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@yahoo.com' at line 1

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
$query2="SELECT `User_id` FROM `users` WHERE `E-mail`='".$email."';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is wrong, try this -

> $query2="SELECT `User_id` FROM `users` WHERE `E-mail`='$email'";

Answer (score 1):

Please do everyone, and especially yourself a favor and read through [Preventing SQL-injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3749523)

It will help you write proper queries, preventing someone from using `"; DELETE FROM users;` as an email-address, thereby deleting all your data. It will also fix this error you're currently seeing

Answer (score 0):

just change in `WHERE E-mail='".$email."'"`;